# How do I build and use a common layer for multiple .NET SAM lambda functions within 1 template.yaml?

Tags: aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I have a dotnet SAM project with 10 or so lambda functions.  Each function references code from our codebase, and the size for each function is around 8MB.  So I thought hey why not create a layer with all the common stuff and then have the functions all use that layer.

There are no examples online on how to do this with dotnet/c# and what ends up happening is my layer compiles fine, but then my function has ALL the DLLs that the layer has...I assume because my "lambda function" csproj file references all the same stuff as the "layer" csproj file.

Basic file structure is this:

- template.yaml contains layer and function definition in it
- The layer points to the "layer" directory, which contains a csproj file with the stuff I want my layer to contain.  This builds fine.
- The function refers to the layer, and uses a different csproj file that MUST also reference all the same stuff for the build to work and for my IDE to work.

Here's a snippet of my template.yaml file:

```
Resources:
  MyLambdaLayer:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      LayerName: !Sub ${FunctionNamePrefix}-${Env}-my-layer
      Description: Common code for lambda functions
      ContentUri: layer
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - dotnet6
    Metadata:
      BuildMethod: dotnet6              # Required to have AWS SAM build this layer
  LogHello:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Sub ${FunctionNamePrefix}-${Env}-log-hello
      Handler: LambdaServices.Functions.LogHello::Handle
      Role: !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/LambdaSQSRole
      CodeUri: ''
      Description: 'Says Hello'
      Layers:
        - !Ref MyLambdaLayer
      Events:
        CWSchedule:
          Type: Schedule
          Properties:
            Schedule: rate(1 minute)
```

Question:  Has anybody done this with dotnet using SAM and can you share a simple working example?